# mySQL WHERE.. OR query

Tags: mysql

I want to execute a query on a database to select all rows in the 'Event' table where the 'about' section has any of the following words in it: strokestown, arts, day. My query, shown below is only getting rows that have the first word, strokestown in them. How do I make it search for all words?

```
SELECT *
  FROM Event
 WHERE about LIKE 'strokestown%'
    OR about LIKE 'arts%'
    OR about LIKE 'day%';
```

Thank you for your time!!

Jim

Comment: and here's the explanation on why:  The <like_condition> supports the following patterns:

'ABC%' - where a string begins with the letters 'ABC'
'%XYZ' - where a string ends with the 'XYZ'
'%TUV%' - where the string contains 'TUV' anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this smaller like this: `SELECT * FROM Event WHERE about REGEXP '(strokestown|arts|day)'`

Comment: This of course works (on mysql), but is slower than using 'LIKE' (up to 10 times it seems: http://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/). Personally I'd stick to standard SQL syntax whenever possible and use the nifty special features only if they solve a problem better.

Comment: what is opposite of this like **where not equal to**

Answer (score 8):

Place the wildcard character, '%', at the start as well as the end of the your search terms:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Event 
WHERE about LIKE '%strokestown%' 
OR about LIKE '%arts%' 
OR about LIKE '%day%';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM Event
WHERE about LIKE '%strokestown%'
    OR about LIKE '%arts%'
    OR about LIKE '%day%'
```

Put a % before and after the keywords.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Event WHERE about LIKE '%strokestown%' OR about LIKE '%arts%' OR about LIKE '%day%';
```

Comment: This won't work at all :p  This will mean all the words need to be at the beginning, with anything after it, and since only one word can be at the beginning... well hopefully you get the idea.